# Difficulties parsing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This function call of parsePre is stopping after the first element in the array [ 1, "PHYS112", "PHYS122" ]. It is not continuing onto the next element into the array. I was wondering if there is something stopping the for-loop from continuing on the first call?

```
   var stuff = {
              "subject":"PHYS",
              "catalog_number":"375",
              "title":"Stars",
              "prerequisites":"Prereq: PHYS 112 or 122 and two of PHYS 234, 241, 242, 256, 258\/358, 263, 275",
              "prerequisites_parsed":[
                [ 1, "PHYS112", "PHYS122" ],[ 2,"PHYS234","PHYS241","PHYS242","PHYS256",
                                              [ 1, "PHYS258", "PHYS358"],
                                              "PHYS263", "PHYS275"]]
            };
var pr = stuff.prerequisites_parsed;


var parsePre = function (pre){
  console.log(pre);
  console.log(pre.length);
  for(i = 0; i < pre.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    if(typeof pre[i] === 'number'){
      console.log(pre[i] + " of: ");
    }
    else if(typeof pre[i] === 'string'){
      console.log(pre[i] + ", ");
    }
    else {
      console.log("WE SHOULD RECURSE");
      parsePre(pre[i]);
    }
  }
}

parsePre(pr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursion is broken because each invocation reuses the same `i` variable in the `for`-loop. To fix this, replace your line with:

```
for (var i = 0; ... )
```

---

This is because when you assign to a variable without using `var`, it is treated as a global variable. This is a quirk specific to JavaScript, but not most other languages.

In the future, you can catch these problems by putting this line at the top of your JavaScript code: `"use strict";`

Comment: Using the function scope `"use strict";` is better so you don't inadvertently break non-strict compatible 3rd-party code - *at least for now*